# How to run External Tools in Android Studio programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.5, external-tools

## I) Situation

I have a problem regarding **External tools execution in Android Studio 3.5**.
I can do this from Tools > External Tools (configured from File > Settings > Tools > External Tools) and it works perfectly fine.

My goal is to **programmatically** run it, looking like this:
run.externalTools("toolName");

Unfortunatelly, I did not find such command.

## II) Subsidiary question

Will the external tool be **exported together** with the app?

## III) Environment:

Android Studio 3.5

Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

Thanks for helping,

Nyozha.

Comment: What tool do you want to run? Do you want to start an external tool from your finished Android app? If yes, then this is not possible. All you can do is include external java/kotlin or C++ libraries to your android project and call them from there. But you won't be able to run external tools which are installed on the users device from your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it makes sense that we cannot programmatically run an external tool. My goal is to run a python script. It works perfectly as an external tool. Making it internal will require Kivy, Chaquopy, Beeware, ... right?

Comment: I never did run Python Code in my android app, but yes, you'll need to find a way to include it in your app.